# Validating only 90 days from current date should be enabled in a calendar using Cypress

Tags: automation, calendar, cypress

I am working on a scenario where I need to validate that when I select a date picker only 90 days from the current date should be enabled, rest all the dates should be disabled.

So Could anyone help me with automating this scenario using Cypress

Thanks,
Sanjana

Comment: Please add your HTML along with the code you tried and errors if you are facing any.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.